# Publish ASP.NET Core MVC website with Entity Framework Core on hosting with appsettings.json

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, web-hosting

How can I publish my website ASP.NET with `appsetting.json`? I watch many deploy their website with `Web.config` file and only change Connection String but I use appsetting.json. How can I use it ? Please help
My project don't have file `Web.config`, it's only have `Starup.cs` file and `Program.cs` file and it run normally on localhost without `Web.config` but when deploy on hosting it's need `Web.config`, I'm so confused

My `Program.cs` file

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var startup = new Startup(builder.Configuration); // My custom startup class.

startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services); // Add services to the container.

var app = builder.Build();

startup.Configure(app, app.Environment); // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.Run();
```

My `appsetting.json` file

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "db2T": "Server=DESKTOP-9NQ1AQE\\QUANGTRUONG;Database=dbMarkets;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=true;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

My `Starup.cs` file

```
using AspNetCoreHero.ToastNotification;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Text.Unicode;
using Web2T.Models;

public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.Configuration = configuration;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add serices to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var stringConnectdb = Configuration.GetConnectionString("db2T");
        services.AddDbContext<DbMarketsContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(stringConnectdb));
        services.AddSingleton<HtmlEncoder>(HtmlEncoder.Create(allowedRanges: new[] { UnicodeRanges.All }));
        services.AddSession();
        services.AddHttpClient();
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(p =>
                {
                    p.LoginPath = "/dang-nhap.html";
                    p.AccessDeniedPath = "/";
                });
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        services.AddNotyf(config => { config.DurationInSeconds = 3; config.IsDismissable = true; config.Position = NotyfPosition.BottomRight; });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(WebApplication app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "areas",
                pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

    }
}
```

I tried change my Connection String like Connection String on host but it's not work

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net Core will use appsetting.json's connection string instead of using web.config.

The web.config's settings is just for the IIS(windows) not for the Asp.net Core application itself, since asp.net core is cross-platform.

So after you publish your application, if you select publish to windows, it will generate the web.config which used to tell the IIS host to run your asp.net core application.

If you want to modify the connection string,  you just need to modify the appsetting.json's connection string value. Then the application will use it automatically.